# Magento getting Sql Error for M2ePro Module after Upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, database, m2epro

After Upgrade Magento 1.7 to 1.9.3 Getting below error on M2ePro Module Backend

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Ess_M2ePro_Controller_Adminhtml_BaseController::_addContent() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Block_Abstract, boolean given, called in E:\Personal\Project\xampp\htdocs\maya-clone-2810\app\code\community\Ess\M2ePro\controllers\Adminhtml\SupportController.php on line 49 and defined in E:\Personal\Project\xampp\htdocs\maya-clone-2810\app\code\community\Ess\M2ePro\Controller\Adminhtml\BaseController.php:105 Stack trace: #0 E:\Personal\Project\xampp\htdocs\maya-clone-2810\app\code\community\Ess\M2ePro\controllers\Adminhtml\SupportController.php(49): Ess_M2ePro_Controller_Adminhtml_BaseController->_addContent(false) #1 E:\Personal\Project\xampp\htdocs\maya-clone-2810\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Ess_M2ePro_Adminhtml_SupportController->indexAction() #2 E:\Personal\Project\xampp\htdocs\maya-clone-2810\app\code\community\Ess\M2ePro\Controller\Adminhtml\BaseController.php(48): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index') #3 E:\Personal\Pro in E:\Personal\Project\xampp\htdocs\maya-clone-2810\app\code\community\Ess\M2ePro\Controller\Adminhtml\BaseController.php on line 105
```

Can any one help me on this

Comment: upgrade m2epro and check.

Comment: @shyam : thanks for reply after upgrade i am getting new error please take a look

Comment: magento upgrade or module upgrade?

Comment: Module Upgrade from magento connect store i compared files & updated